# How to move my math stackexchange account to another e-mail? Thanks!!

Tags: support, user-accounts, profile-page

Hi am a statistical consultant building a portfolio and hence would like only my stats stack exchange account to be available online and would like to move the math stackexchange account of mine to another e-mail. Can someone do this for me? I will be extremely glad to give you an e-mail to which Id like to move it. In that case, I can edit my profile with name and details in my stat stackexchange and allow it to be searched on the web and point it in my profile. This would be great! Let me know moderators!

I only want my stats(cross validated) account to show up in my profile. How can I do that ?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There should be an "edit" link on your profile page that you can use to change your email address.

$\hspace{1cm}$[image]

Comment: Would that unlink my stats and math stack exchange accounts in my stats stackexchange profile- where my math and scientific computing and theoretical computer science and other links show up!

Comment: Your accounts should still be linked. Your accounts are linked when they are created or, if created using a different email, by SE action. As Mad Scientist says, moderators do not have a way to adjust account linkages.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for moderators to unlink accounts, this is not really supported by SE. You can try to use the "Contact us" link at the bottom of the page and ask SE directly if they can unlink your accounts, but I'm not sure if they do that.

There is also the nuclear option of account unlinking which is requesting the deletion of one of the accounts.

Comment: I am very open with the deletion of the math account. Can the moderators do that? If not- I will try contacting the SE guys. Thanks!

Comment: @VSPC: If you need to delete your Math.SE account, moderators can do that. However, I would suggest using the [contact us](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help) link to contact SE to break the linkage, instead.

Comment: Thank you. I would do the contact us first, and then try the delete - only as the last option.

Comment: W.r.t to the above question and suggestions- I would like the moderators to delete my math S.E account. Thanks! This is an affirmative confirmation. Go ahead.